# How to write this regular expression in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, regex

My coworker needs me to write him a regular expression for his vb.net app.

I do not know vb and he does not know regex.

The regex he needs is:

```
/.*web id: ?(\d+).*/i
```

Basically he needs to search a string for something like "web id: 345" or "web id:2534" and retrieve the ID.

He took what I gave him above and was able to put this together:

```
Dim strPattern As String = ".*web id: ?(\d+).*"
Dim strReplacement$ = "$1"

GetWebId$ = Regex.Replace(LCase$(strNote$), strPattern$, strReplacement$)
```

However I am not sure how you pass the case-insensitive flag? (his current fix for that is making the whole string lowercase first)

Also one thing I can't seem to figure out is when he runs this on a string with multiple lines, any text that is not on the same line as "web id: \d" is also being returned which i find strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag:

```
Regex.Replace(strNote, strPattern, strReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

If you are going to ignore case there should be no need to use `LCase`. I also find it odd that you have all those `$` symbols in your variable names - they shouldn't be valid in either C# or VB.NET.

---

**EDIT #2:** I realize you may have wanted to replace the entire line that matched with the `$1` replacement pattern to match the ID. If you have a need to use multiple options you can `Or` them together as follows:

```
Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

---

**EDIT #1:** you are using the wrong method to extract the ID. You have a group `(\d+)` to capture the ID, but you are using `Regex.Replace` on your match, which is why you get everything else in the text. To match the ID use the following:

```
Dim input As String = "foo web id:2010 bar"
Dim pattern As String = ".*web id: ?(\d+).*"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If m.Success Then
    Dim id As String = m.Groups(1).Value
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " & id)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("No Match!")
End If
```

You will notice we refer to `Groups(1)` which holds the value captured by the `(\d+)` group. Patterns with more groups may lead to confusion, especially with nested groups. In those cases you can use named groups. Here is the same code updated to use named groups:

```
Dim input As String = "foo web id:2010 bar"
Dim pattern As String = ".*web id: ?(?<ID>\d+).*" ' group name added '
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If m.Success Then
    ' refer to group by group name '
    Dim id As String = m.Groups("ID").Value
    Console.WriteLine("ID: " & id)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("No Match!")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, my bigger issue though was when running this on multi-line text.

Comment: @John see my updates. If you still have issues please updated your post with some sample input with "multi-line" text.

Comment: @John great! I also added another edit to show how to combine multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of unrelated, but *this code is a collection of things you shouldn’t do in VB.NET.*

You shouldn’t use the old `$` suffix on string variables, and likewise you shouldn’t use old functions such as `LCase$`. There are equivalent functions in the framework that should be used. You can also tell your friend to always enable `Option Strict` while where at it. This will catch a lot of potential bugs.

Furthermore, to set the return value of a function, the … “more established” method is to use `Return …`, not `Functionname = …`.

So the “correct” code will look like this:

```
''// I’m assuming that `GetWebId` is the name of the function we’re in.
Function GetWebId(note As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String = ".*web id: ?(\d+).*"
    Dim replacement As String = "$1"
    Return Regex.Replace(note.ToLower(), pattern, replacement)
End Function
```

See Ahmad’s solution of how to get the “ignorecase” flag into the expression.

Comment: Thanks, I found out to handle the multi-line issue he was having he needed to include the flag, `RegexOptions.Singline`. Is there a way he can pass 2 options?