# Use VB.net Regex to extract two parts of a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have strings that follow the format `"x Packs of y"` so for example `"15 packs of 5"`, `"1 pack of 10"` and so on.

I would like to use a regex that looks for `"x Packs of y"` and puts `x` in one variable and `y` in a second variable.

Please can somebody advise how I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In .NET, for ASCII Digits, use `[0-9]`, not `\d`**

In .NET, `\d` matches digits in any script, including Thai and Klingon. Assuming you only want ASCII digits 0 through 9 rather than `654۳۲١८৮੪૯୫୬१७੩௮`, use this:

```
Dim firstNumber As String
Dim secondNumber As String
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("([0-9]+) packs? of ([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
firstNumber = RegexObj.Match(yourString).Groups(1).Value
secondNumber = RegexObj.Match(yourString).Groups(2).Value
```

**Explanation**

- `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` makes it case-insensitive
- `([0-9]+)` captures one or more digits to Group 1
- `packs?` matches `pack` with an optional `s`
- `([0-9]+)` captures one or more digits to Group 2
- the code retrieves groups 1 and 2

Comment: I would have ticked all three responses if I could. I chose this one though because it is the one I eventually went with.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
Dim foo = "15 packs of 5"

Dim match = Regex.Match(foo, "(\d+) packs? of (\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dim x = match.Groups(1).Value
Dim y = match.Groups(2).Value

Console.WriteLine("x = " & x)
Console.WriteLine("y = " & y)
```

[**Live Demo - Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HfBfa2)

Update: Thanks Braj for pointing out the pack/packs.

Comment: what about this `1 pack of 10`

Comment: Don;t you think its same that I used.

Answer (score 3):

Get the matched group from index 1 and 2

```
(\d+) packs? of (\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sR4oP7/3)

String literals for use in programs: C# (ignore case is also added)

```
@"(?i)(\d+) packs? of (\d+)"
```

---

Read more about [Ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709971/how-to-write-this-regular-expression-in-vb-net) and [Regex.Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet)

Comment: Thanks. Do I just use Regex.Match?

Comment: you regex matches `\d pack of \d`.. why is there a `?`

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is fine. `?` means 0 or 1.

Comment: @sunbabaphu It's to match both `packs` and `pack` as well

Comment: are u using singular/plural logic for pack?  i.e. `pack | packs`

Comment: @sunbabaphu yes. here `s` is 0 and 1 time.

Comment: @sunbabaphu see the sample that OP is posted in question.

Comment: terribly sorry! i missed that. did try your code though.. here: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=162c1e5a-a2d5-40e8-8605-f43ba1fc8d59

Comment: @Braj Yeah there's a serial downvoter on this thread, got one too, very suspicious. Hopefully not a case of strategic downvoting. :)

Comment: Zx81 Well it's not me... I up voted braj earlier and you just now to counteract the down votes. :)